# Cannot figure out how to make THIS particular data set long-form (theory, not even code)

Tags: dataset, tableau, reshape, data-stream-mining

I am a tableau developer, but I know Python, stats, and, in short, I think you all will be best able to solve my problem.

- There is a universal filter on Facility.  This means that any dataset/sheet can only have one field equal to facility.
- Data table looks like this: [Time] [Departure=facilities] [Arrival=facilities]
- Departure and Arrival are both fields that contain facility names. The goal is to make a chart that shows the quantity of arrivals and departures for a chosen facility (let's say, by hour... my times are exact to the second but I'm willing to bin to fix my problem. Also, time does apply to both departure airport and arrival; it's a chosen time by FAA to describe the flight).
- How can I transform this dataset so that there is only one field designated as facility? Facility can only be one column, but I need the quantities of arrivals and departures.  **One more catch:** this is a live data stream. I am not reshaping for data analysis, this is real-time.  My fields need to be calculated fields (they can include the names of the original fields, and the calculations can include anything that you can think of in excel... there are equal if not more available functions in tableau, but the language is slightly different;cI figure more people would be able to help if I said "feel free to write the calculated fields as you would in excel" because I can easily translate any differences myself. Any input from any sort of expertise is appreciated! Even the "theory" to describe how this would be done eludes me, so please offer any thoughts.

Comment: Do you need code in tableau ? 
Seems pretty straightforward

Comment: Facility can only equal one field.  But I have two fields that are facility.  If I were to picture the goal in my head, it is one column named facility, and the number of arrivals, the number of departures for every hour  and departures per hour.  I agree with you that, considering there are three columns here, it does SEEM straightforward. but i can't graph departure quantities and arrival quantities as two lines, because facility can only equal one field. Filter is universal for 13 datasources.  Each datasource/set needs to blend to facility on one field.

Comment: By "code" I mean that I'm sure this will involve "calculated fields."  To create a calc field, a big box opens up, and it's written with things like "IF, THEN, { }, END"... it's like a flavor of DAX in complicated situations.

Answer (score 0):

You tack on a column denoting I’d the row corresponds to an arrival or a departure. Then the rest of your columns describe what they describe for that particular event. If the facility is London-Heathrow, this new column will say if the event is an arrival or a departure, and you do it need separate columns for the arrival and departure facilities.

You’ll end up with a fairly long data frame (since you’ll be doubling the number of rows), but if you need a long format instead of wide, then that sounds acceptable.